# Documentum.cmis.too many open files error

Tags: cmis, rhel7, documentum, tomcat8.5

We have deployed our application on rhel 7 from rhel 6 and after deployment we are seeing following error in the catalina.properties, due to this my vm link is getting down frequently. We are using Documentum CMIS 16.4 version on tomcat 8.5 version.

***Following is the error's details:***

```
27-Nov-2018 01:57:00.536 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-0.0.0.0-12510-Acceptor-0] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Acceptor.run Socket accept failed
 java.io.IOException: Too many open files
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:422)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:250)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Acceptor.run(NioEndpoint.java:457)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

***Here are my efforts in order to solve this problem:*** 
I have increased ulimit value from 1024 to 8192 for specific user and rebooted it, recycled tomcat service but nothing happened. I had done changed to file named `/etc/security/limits.d/20-nproc.conf/20-nproc.conf`. kindly help here.

Comment: Sounds like something is opening files and not closing them, if that is the case then increasing the limit will only postpone the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have privileges to add a comment, so posting as an answer. Try to find out which files are open by using the command 
`lsof -p <pid> | wc -l`.

That will tell you which files are not getting closed. 
You can also check the limits of a running process by 
`cat /proc/<pid>/limits`